# What is the geometric meaning of $||2z||>||z^2+1||$?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the Volkovyski book and I'm having trouble with the following problem :
(Consider $z\in\mathbb{C}$)

Describe the geometric meaning of the following relationship:

$$||2z||>||z^2+1||$$

I already know that $||2z||$ is a circle in the origin with radius equal to 1/2, but what is $||z^2+1||$ ?

If I let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$ then the relation $||z^2+1||=\lambda$ is not always a simple curve, so what is the geometric meaning of $||z^2+1||<||2z||$?

Comment: Just a remark, but $|2z|$ is not a circle, it is just an expression. The relation $|2z|=1$ looks like a circle when you plot it in the complex plane, and for example the relation $|2z| = |2z|$ is the entire plane when you plot it, so it is an important distinction

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment. I was just trying to visualize what could represent the relations between the expressions, and to do so I separated them into two expressions to see how they behaved when equal to some constant.

Comment: You should leave Problem 1 here & make a new Question to cover Problem 2. I will try to make that change , which you can revert if that is not satisfactory.

Comment: Some Downvoter seems to not like my Answer , though it is essentially Correct. No Comment or Constructive feedback was given hence not sure what the Issue is.

Comment: Knowing what $f(x)=C$ and $g(x)=C$ look like is generally not a useful way to understand what $f(x)=g(x)$ looks like.

Comment: Your question should be "What is the locus of points $z  \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|2z|>|z^2+1|$"

Comment: @Parker Emmerson ; your (erased) answer has a strong "Chat GTP" flavour. What is the point to copy-paste such **completely nonsense** texts ?

Comment: Thanks for the insight , @Jean-ClaudeArbaut , I get what you want to convey. When answer downvote is due to question , I have seen some users put that in a comment , which at least gives the thought behind the downvote. Here , there is no feedback at all.

Answer (score 1):

Without having the Volkovyski book , I am not sure what technique has been introduced & what method we have to use.

Here is what I would try :
Consider $z=x+iy$
then we will have $||2z||=\sqrt{(2x)^2+(2y)^2}$
We can calculate $z^2+1$ & then calculate $||z^2+1||$

The given "Equation" can then be written like this :

$\sqrt{(2X)^2+(2Y)^2} = \sqrt{[(X^2-Y^2+1)]^2+(2XY)^2}$
$(2X)^2+(2Y)^2 = [(X^2-Y^2+1)]^2+(2XY)^2$

Algebra can expand the terms & rearrange to make it $f(x,y)g(x,y)=0$ which can then be interpreted.

Plotting is one alternate technique.

Plot that Equation to see that it is 2 Circles :

[image: PLOT 1]

Plot $(2X)^2+(2Y)^2 < [(X^2-Y^2+1)]^2+(2XY)^2$ :

[image: PLOT 2]

Plot $(2X)^2+(2Y)^2 > [(X^2-Y^2+1)]^2+(2XY)^2$ :

[image: PLOT 3]

We can expand the terms & re-arrange to get the 2 Circles , without the Visualizations [[ courtesy of Wolfram Online Tool ! ]] through algebra.
It will be like :
$[(X-A_1)^2+(Y-B_1)^2-C_1^2][(X-A_2)^2+(Y-B_2)^2-C_2^2]=0$
That gives :
A Circle with Center at $(A_1,B_1)$ & radius $C_1$
A Circle with Center at $(A_2,B_2)$ & radius $C_2$

A little bit of algebra gives :
$A_1=0$ , $B_1=+1$ , $C_1=1.5$
$A_2=0$ , $B_2=-1$ , $C_2=1.5$

Geometric Interpretation , in normal English , is that it is the Set of Points which are in Exactly 1 Circle , excluding the Points which are Both Circles & excluding the Points which are in neither Circle.